# Stanford math qual: Linear rep of a $p$-group over $\Bbb{F}_p$ fixes a line pointwise

Tags: representation-theory

I'm trying to solve a qual question that goes as follows.

> > Let $H$ be a $p$-group and $V$ a finite dimensional linear representation of $H$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$. Then there is a vector $v \in V$ that is fixed pointwise by $H$.

When $H$ is cyclic of order $p$, this is easy to do. We choose $h\in H$ a generator of order $p$. As an endomorphism of $V$, $h$ satisfies $ (h-1)^p  = h^p - 1 = 0.$ Hence there is $v \in V$ such that $hv = v$. Since $H = \langle h\rangle$, we are done. However, if $H$ is not cyclic, how can I go about doing this?

My idea when $H$ is not cyclic is to choose an element of order $p$ in the center of $H$, but that idea doesn't seem to go anywhere. Also, what is special about $\Bbb{F}_p$ (and not just ***any*** field of characteristic $p$) that I'm not using here? There's a second part  to the question that asks one to show that the same is true over $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of elements in $V$ is a power of $p$. Because $H$ is a $p$-group, its orbits on $V$ have sizes that are also powers of $p$. Therefore the number of singleton orbits is a multiple of $p$. Because the zero vector forms a singleton orbit, there must be others.

Part two? There are finitely many entries in the matrices representing elements of $H$. Because all those matrix entries are algebraic over $\Bbb{F}_p$ they all belong to some finite subfield of $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$. Proceed as in part one.

---

An alternative solution (summary of the discussion in the comments with some key contributions from Ben Lim) is to use induction on $|H|$. The base case $|H|=p$ was covered in the question.

- We can replace $V$ with any non-trivial subspace stable under $H$, so (as $\dim V<\infty$) w.l.o.g. we can assume that $V$ is an irreducible representation of $H$ (it suffices to find that trivial 1-dimensional representation within an irreducible submodule of the original module).
- Let $h$ be an element of order $p$ in the center $Z(H)$. As deduced in the question $h$ has an eigenvector belonging to eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.
- By Schur's lemma $h$ acts on all of $V$ as a scalar. By the previous bullet that scalar has to be one.
- If $K$ is the subgroup generated by $h$, then $K\unlhd H$. By the previous bullet we can view $V$ as a linear representation of $H_1=H/K$ by inflation.
- $|H_1|<|H|$, so by induction hypothesis $V$ has a 1-dimensional subspace $U$ such that $H_1$ acts trivially on it.
- Clearly $H$ acts trivially on $U$, and we are done.

Comment: IOW the only thing about the fact that $V$ is a **linear** representation that we need is zero being a fixed point. Otherwise it is just about counting orbits of the group action.

Comment: I see. I was completely misled with my approach. I guess with these qual questions you either see the right way or not.

Comment: Not sure about that, @Ben. There may be equally good or better ways of seeing this.

Comment: Is there an approach along the lines of what I was trying to argue above? Note my argument for $H$ cyclic of order $p$ just uses the fact that the ground field has characteristic $p$.

Comment: @BenLim: May be? If you can show that either there is a stable line, or the center has a non-trivial subgroup acting trivially on all of $V$, then you can mod out that subgroup of the center and proceed by induction on $|H|$.

Comment: Actually, I tried something like this earlier. Consider $Z(H)$, choose $h\in Z(H)$ of order $p$. Then writing $K := \langle h\rangle$ and applying the same argument as above, we see that $K$ fixes a line in $V$. I'm not sure how to show that $K$ acts trivially on all of $V$; if $V$ were an irreducible representation of $H$ then I think this works by Schur's lemma, but it's not in our case.

Comment: @BenLim: But you can always restrict your attention to an irreducible submodule $W$ of $V$! If you find a fixed point vector in $W$, that remains a fixed point in $V$ also, no?

Comment: I'll have to think more about this; in particular how I can find such a $W$ containing my fixed point vector.

Comment: First pick $W$, then start looking for fixed points.

Comment: Yes. Because $V$ finite dimensional. If there is no subspace stable under the action of $H$, then $V$ is irreducible. If there is, call it $V_1\subset V$. Either it is irreducible or it has an even smaller stable subspace $V_2\subset V_1$. The chain $\cdots V_2\subset V_1\subset V$ must stop at some point, because the dimension keeps dropping and cannot go below 1.

Comment: Thanks for the second part of your answer Jyrki. I have to say though that it is very similar to the problem of showing that for a finite group $G$, $Z(G) = \{ g \in G : \chi(g) = \chi(1) \hspace{1mm} \text{for all irreducible characters $\chi$} \}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the first argument given by Jyrki Lahtonen as an application of the [$p$-group fixed point theorem](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/the-p-group-fixed-point-theorem/), which just says that if a (finite) $p$-group $G$ acts on a (finite) set $X$ then

$$|X^G| \equiv |X| \bmod p$$

and in particular if $|X|$ isn't divisible by $p$ then the action has a fixed point. It's surprisingly useful to have a name for this result; in the linked post I give a whole bunch of applications of it.